# Problema com atualização de um Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-activity

Estou aprendendo Android e ao tentar desenvolver um aplicativo eu me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma Activity que possui dois Fragments: `ReminderListFragment` e `FilterListFragment`. O primeiro fragment possui uma lista de Reminders e o segundo, uma lista de filtros com o nome e a quantidade de itens cadastrados em cada filtro. Entretanto, quanto excluo algum Reminder, os valores de `FilterListFragment` não são atualizados. A mesma coisa acontece quando eu excluo um dos filtros (nesse caso ele exclui todos os registros referentes ao filtro selecionado), ele não atualiza a lista de Reminders.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código referente a `FilterListFragment`:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.context_menu_category) {
                // Used to verify it it is the right context_menu //Gets the item
                // position and gets the category in that position:
                AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                Category category = ((CategoryFilter) lvFilters.getAdapter().getItem(info.position)).getCategory();

                // Switch between the options in the context menu(Edit and Delete)
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.edit:
                    // Passes the current reminder to be edited via Intent and
                    // Invokes edit method
                    DialogFragment newFragment = EditCategoryDialogFragment.newInstance(category);
                    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "" + R.string.dialog_editcategory_title);
                    updateListView();
                    return true;
                case R.id.delete:
                    // Invokes delete method
                    try {
                        // Deletes from the bank;
                        Controller.instance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).deleteReminderByCategory(category);
                        Controller.instance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).deleteCategory(category);
                        updateListView();
                        return true;
                    } catch (DBException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                    updateListView();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
                }

            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Código referente a `ReminderListFragment`:

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.context_menu_reminder) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            Reminder reminder = (Reminder) contextMenuAdapter.getItem(info.position);
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.edit:
                Intent editIntent = editIntent(reminder);
                editIntent.putExtra("id", reminder.getId());
                editIntent.putExtra("text", reminder.getText());
                editIntent.putExtra("details", reminder.getDetails());
                startActivity(editIntent);
                updateListView(null);
                return true;
            case R.id.delete:
                try {
                    Controller.instance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).deleteReminder(reminder);
                } catch (DBException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                updateListView(null);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Pode nos mostrar o código da função updateListView()? Olhando seu código estou sentindo a falta do metodo info.notifyDataSetChanged(); no seu adapter, provavelmente colocando ele logo após as ações de exclusão resolverá o seu problema, caso você não esteja usando esse metodo dentro do metodo updateListView() então tente utiliza-lo, caso não resolva, poste o código do update que ficará melhor para ajudarmos.

Comment: @EduardoRafaelMoraes eu tentei utilizar o info.notifyDataSetChanged() mas ele diz que o método não existe (ainda sou iniciante, não sei te dizer com precisão sobre isso, desculpe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver esse problema adicionando os seguintes métodos:

Na classe `FilterListFragment`:

```
public void reloadReminderListFragment() {
        Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listReminders);
        if (currentFragment instanceof ReminderListFragment) {
            FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = (getActivity()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
            fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
            fragTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```

Na classe `ReminderListFragment`:

```
public void reloadFilterListFragment() {
        Fragment currentFragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.listCategories);
        if (currentFragment instanceof FilterListFragment) {
            FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = (getActivity()).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
            fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
            fragTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
```